# Index out of bounds exception error

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code which appears to generate an array error on the following bit:

```
int run = 0;

    while(myNet.RunNet(q) > 0.2 && run < 1000) {

        myNet.TrainNet(templates, 10);
        run += 1;

    }
```

Point is, when I run TrainNet on templates outside the loop it does not return the same error... :S

```
public void SetInput(ArrayList<Double> inputs) {

    ArrayList<Neuron> inputNeurons = networkLayers.get(0).getLayerNeurons();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputNeurons.size(); i++) {

        inputNeurons.get(i).ResetInput();
        inputNeurons.get(i).ReceiveInput(inputs.get(i));

    }

}
```

Which returns

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at NeuralNet.Network.SetInput(Network.java:82)
at NeuralNet.Network.TrainNet(Network.java:100)
at nnTest.RunNet.main(RunNet.java:90)
```

For:

```
ArrayList<Double> m = new ArrayList<Double>();
    m.add(0.0);
    m.add(0.0);
    m.add(0.0);

    ArrayList<Double> n = new ArrayList<Double>();
    n.add(1.0);
    n.add(1.0);
    n.add(0.0);

    ArrayList<Double> o = new ArrayList<Double>();
    o.add(1.0);
    o.add(0.0);
    o.add(1.0);

    ArrayList<Double> p = new ArrayList<Double>();
    p.add(1.0);
    p.add(1.0);
    p.add(1.0);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> templates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
    templates.add(m);
    templates.add(n);
    templates.add(o);
    templates.add(p);
```

Parsed through

```
public void TrainNet(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> templates, int epochs) {


    int j = 1;

    for(ArrayList<Double> currentTemplate : templates) {
        System.out.println("------------------------");
        System.out.println("Testing through set " + j);
        j += 1;

        outputNeuron.setDesired(currentTemplate.get(0));
        currentTemplate.remove(0);
        SetInput(currentTemplate);

        for(int i = 0; i < epochs; i++) {

            FeedForward();
            BackPropagate();


        }

    }

}

public void SetInput(ArrayList<Double> inputs) {

    ArrayList<Neuron> inputNeurons = networkLayers.get(0).getLayerNeurons();

    for(int i = 0; i < inputNeurons.size(); i++) {

        inputNeurons.get(i).ResetInput();
        inputNeurons.get(i).ReceiveInput(inputs.get(i));

    }

}
```

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: I suggest you step through your code in your debugger and you are likely to see that the size of the two collections are you accessing is not the same.

Comment: i is < inputNeurons.size(), not inputs.size().

Answer (score 1):

```
inputNeurons.get(i).ReceiveInput(inputs.get(i));
```

With `inputs.get(i)`, you are assuming that `inputs` has at least as many entries as `inputNeurons`.  It probably doesn't so you are exceeding its bounds.

Comment: Well, yes, but if I run myNet.TrainNet(templates, 10); outside the loop then it does not give the same error...

Answer (score 0):

Right here:

```
inputNeurons.get(i).ReceiveInput(inputs.get(i));
```

You haven't done anything to ensure that `i` is in bounds for `inputs`.

At a minimun, the error message told you where to look:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at NeuralNet.Network.SetInput(Network.java:82)
at NeuralNet.Network.TrainNet(Network.java:100)
at nnTest.RunNet.main(RunNet.java:90)
```

An `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` was thrown, emanating from `java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck` from `java.util.ArrayList.get` from `NeuralNet.Network.SetInput` which is *your* code complete with offending line number `82`. Look at line `82`. It's the line I highlighted above. That's how you debug these sorts of issues.

Also, I encourage you to train yourself in attaching a debugger and working through bugs with the assistance of such.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be lying in this statement:

```
inputNeurons.get(i).ReceiveInput(inputs.get(i));
```

i may run out of bounds for inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Have your tried changing your loop condition to

i < inputNeurons.size() - 1

as in the below example?

```
for(int i = 0; i<inputNeurons.size() - 1; i++) {
    inputNeurons.get(i).ResetInput();
    inputNeurons.get(i).ReceiveInput(inputs.get(i));
}
```